# Рекурсивный вызов процедуры внутри цикла

Tags: циклы, рекурсия

Верно ли, что рекурсивный вызов [процедуры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0) внутри цикла - это плохое решение? Надо ли разделять циклы и рекурсивные вызовы?

Answer (score 3):

Неверно. Утверждение необоснованное. Аналогия ... Что хуже - вызвать сто раз процедуру в цикле, или сделать 10 рекурсивных вызовов по 10? Использованием стека в данном случае можно смело пренебречь. Хорошее решение то, которое реализует необходимый функционал без необоснованно-большого оверхеда. Имхо.